# Permission Overwrites not working on discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made this so when a user react to the emoji, it creates a channel. It work but the problem is **it's not changing the channel's permission** at all. It just creates the channel

**DJS version: 12.5.3**

```
reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`capsule-${user.username}`, {
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: user.id,
                            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                        },
                        {
                            id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                        }
                    ],
                    type: 'text',
                    parent: '840571873242513418',
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the documentation at [`<TextChannel>.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.3/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions).
It should be more efficient to overwrite permissions on an already existent channel than `.create()`.